# C# getAll Function advice

Tags: c#, crud

Hi I am trying to create CRUD functions in C# but am stuck on my first one which is FetchALL, as so far it says not all code path returns a value.

Heres my code so far

```
  public SqlDataReader FetchAll(string tableName)
        {  



        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString,))
    { 

    string query = "SELECT * FROM  " + tableName;
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    conn.Open();


    conn.Close();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I can give you more information, thanks

Comment: You never `return` anything, but you declared the function to return a `SqlDataReader`. Also, SQL-Injection is possible in `string query = "SELECT * FROM  " + tableName;`.

Comment: If you do choose to return a `SqlDataReader`, ensure it's properly closed and disposed of by the caller, it's easy to start leaking sql connections otherwise.

Comment: Don't be afraid of trying to interpret the error yourself. Read it and try and understand it literally. Not all code paths (i.e. NOT every path of execution) return values. This can be catered for/solved by ensuring ALL paths return a value. Ask yourself if at least one return statement can be reached all of the time. Start by including one!

Comment: Lewis, I've rolled back your recent changes because modifying your question in such a way is against the rules.  If you have a new question, ask a *new* question on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a return type of `SqlDataReader`, but you aren't returning anything anywhere in your code.  At the very least you should declare your data reader and return it like this:

```
public SqlDataReader FetchAll(string tableName)
{
    SqlDataReader reader;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
    {

        string query = "SELECT * FROM  " + tableName;

        // added using block for your command (thanks for pointing that out Alex K.)
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open(); // <-- moved this ABOVE the execute line.
            reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // <-- using the reader declared above.
            //conn.Close(); <-- not needed.  using block handles this for you.
        }
    }

    return reader;
}
```

Note, I've noted a few other problems I saw as well, which you can see by my comments.

Also, I want to point out something very important: **you should always avoid string concatenation in queries as this opens you up to the risk of a SQL injection attack** (as gmiley has duly pointed out).  In this case, you should create an enum which contains values associated with all the possible table names, and then use a dictionary to look up the table names based on their enum values.  If a user provides an invalid/unknown value, you would then thrown an argument exception.

---

This isn't the end of your problems, though (as Default has pointed out).  You can't create the connection in a `using` block, which disposes and closes as soon as it exits the block, and then use the `SqlDataReader` that is returned from the method.  If I were you, I'd return a `DataSet` instead of a `SqlDataReader`.  Here's how I'd do it:

First, create your enum of possible table values:

```
public enum Table
{
    FirstTable,
    SecondTable
}
```

And a dictionary that maps table enum values to the table names (which you will populate in your static constructor):

```
private static Dictionary<Table, string> _tableNames = new Dictionary<Table, string>(); // populate this in your static constructor.
```

And then here is your method to fetch the data:

```
public static System.Data.DataSet FetchAll(Table fromTable)
{
    var ret = new System.Data.DataSet();

    using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        string tableName = "";
        if (!_tableNames.TryGetValue(fromTable, out tableName)) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(@"The table value ""{0}"" is not known.", fromTable.ToString()));
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tableName);

        using (var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            using (var adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ret);
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

One final note, I'd advise you name your class-level variables with lower camel case per convention, e.g. `_connectionString`.

Comment: I deleted my answer as yours was cleaner, since you are fixing some of the various problems, for completeness, I'll mention a couple here: SQL Injection is the top problem with this function, if you have to do it this way, put the table names in a dictionary and lookup the string value using an enumeration. Also, the parameter is simply never checked before it being used.

Comment: Updated my comment to provide a solution to the sql injection problem.

Comment: @gmiley -- Actually, it's not executing a dynamic sql statement, so the query has to be constructed.

Comment: It's concatenating a SQL query together to execute on the server. This is definitely a SQL Injection threat.

Comment: @gmiley -- Sure, I agree, but you can't use parameters for table names.  I like your suggestion about the enums, though.

Comment: Sure, with a `string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0};", lookupDictionary[mytableEnum.Employees]);` obviously,that would require constructing a public `Dictionary<myTableEnum, string> lookupDictionary` somewhere, as well as the enumeration.

Comment: @gmiley -- Right, but that's not SQL parameters, that's string formatting which is a stylistic choice.  I agree on the dictionary and enum approach, though.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: when using `Entity Framework` the context's scope can end, which, if you haven't populated the result, ends in an `Exception` when you try to access the result. I am unfamiliar with `SqlConnection` though, but wouldn't `SqlDataReader` require an open `SqlConnection` when reading? Because, as you state, `using` closes the `SqlConnection`. Do correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: I believe that is correct actually. All of the work should be done in this function to copy the data to a `DataTable` and return that after closing/disposing the `SqlDataReader` and `SqlConnection`.

Comment: @Default Yes - just verified it, [it does indeed error](http://imgur.com/19D4qhH).

Comment: `string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0};", new SqlCommandBuilder().QuoteIdentifier(tableName))`

Comment: @gmiley -- Agreed (though I've always used a DataSet for some reason).  See update.

Comment: @rorayap thanks so much for your detailed answer, i really appreciate it.             but i have to use an sqlreader for this task but will bear in mind the other method for the future, With the first method i am getting an error Line 37: 'reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // <-- using the reader declared above' Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'.

Comment: @Lewis -- You're welcome.  I've used this approach a lot and it seems to work well.

Comment: @Lewis what is your entire query after you build it?

Comment: @roryap Sorry i am unsure what you mean, so far i have just a get all which is bound to a grid view, on the line 37 i am getting An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code, which i think is down to the getall query. Is this the information you are after?

Comment: No, I just want to know what is the value of `query`?  From your error, it's not valid SQL, so I want to know what the SQL statement is.

Comment: @Lewis Can you place a break point in this function and report back what is in the `tableName` variable, as well as then what is in the `query` variable?

Comment: @roryap I reconnected to the database and rebound the object, i am pretty sure it works now, but will start testing it properly with a select list, thanks very much i have marked your very helpful in depth answer as the one.

Comment: @roryap Hi I am getting an error Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'. I was wondering what the problem may be? 
Line 42:                     //uses the reader to execute command
Line 43:                     reader = command.ExecuteReader(); I have updated the code to the recent version at the top

Comment: @Lewis -- I'm not sure, but that's a completely different question.  You can't string questions together; you'll have to ask a new question.

Comment: @roryap hi okay thanks it's for that code above its getting that error

Comment: @Lewis -- I rolled back your changes because you are not allowed to make substantive changes that alters the question after people have answered the question as it was before.  Like I said, if you have a different question, ask a new one through the site.

Comment: Hi okay thanks the issue is due to the SQL reader being returned, I think that i should do  command.ExecuteNonQuery(); instead but still need to return a vaule

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you aren't returning anything from the method.  I'd add, are you sure you want to return a SqlDataReader?  It is declared within a using block, so it will be closed by the time you return it anyway.  I think you should re-evaluate what this function should return.

Comment: Thanks yer I just need to return something otherwise the fucntion isn't picked up by gridview, but am unsure what i need to return

Answer (score 1):

You need a return statment for the method to return a value.